# Convert Columns into rows DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| Name | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTU | 2 | 3 | 0 | 9 | 7 |
| BTP | 1 | 2 | 7 | 9 | 0 |

And I want this:

| Name | letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTU | A | 2 |
| BTU | B | 3 |
| BTU | C | 0 |
| BTU | D | 9 |
| BTU | E | 7 |
| BTP | A | 1 |
| BTP | B | 2 |
| BTP | C | 7 |
| BTP | D | 9 |
| BTP | E | 0 |

How can I do it?

Comment: Please define how the raw data is represented. It is not clear in the question

Comment: I am sorry, now is ready

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], var_name='letter', value_name='Value').sort_values(by='Name', ascending=False)
```

Result:

|  | Name | letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BTU | A | 2 |
| 2 | BTU | B | 3 |
| 4 | BTU | C | 0 |
| 6 | BTU | D | 9 |
| 8 | BTU | E | 7 |
| 1 | BTP | A | 1 |
| 3 | BTP | B | 2 |
| 5 | BTP | C | 7 |
| 7 | BTP | D | 9 |
| 9 | BTP | E | 0 |